# Get all text field values with same class names and put in array using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have some hidden input fields like this ...

```
<input type="hidden" class="added_ids[]" name="added_ids[]" value="5190">
<input type="hidden" class="added_ids[]" name="added_ids[]" value="5340">
<input type="hidden" class="added_ids[]" name="added_ids[]" value="2488">
```

....and so on.

I need to get the values of each of the input fields so that I can pass it as a parameter to my php page.

**url: "index.php/autocomplete/test_search?added_ids[]=" + //array holding ids**

so I need to know how I do it in jQuery ..

Comment: looks like you would have better to serialize it: `var values = $(':hidden').serialize();`  http://jsfiddle.net/hd58F/  Gives you a parameters string that can be passed to server

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var array = $('.added_ids\\[\\]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(array); \\will give you ["5190", "5340", "2488"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()`:

```
var added_ids = $('.added_ids\\[\\]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
var url = "index.php/autocomplete/test_search?added_ids[]=" + added_ids.join();
```

In your PHP you can then retrieve the value and split it by `,` to return it back to an array.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why double slashes? ('\\')

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is passing null. http://localhost/project/index.php/dearch/test_search?added_ids[]=&term=sa

Comment: @JensonMJohn the slashes escape the square bracket character which would break the selector otherwise.

Comment: @user3177114 I cannot access anything hosted on your localhost.